# Plot 1D slice of 2D InterpolatingFunction

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, interpolation

I'm numerically solving a PDE (time+1D space) with `NDSolve` and want to plot some spatial profiles.  `Plot` works, but is very slow compared to `ListPlot`.  Here's an example (Fisher-KPP equation):

```
l = 100;
tmax = 30;
pts = 1000;

sol = NDSolve[{
  D[n[x, t], t] == n[x, t] (1 - n[x, t]) + D[n[x, t], {x, 2}],
  n[x, 0] == If[45 < x < 55, 1, 0], n[0, t] == n[l, t]}, {n}, {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, l}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> pts}}
][[1]];

First@Timing[Plot[Evaluate[n[x, 15] /. sol], {x, 0, l}]]
(* 13.0701 *)

First@Timing[ListLinePlot[Table[{x, n[x, 15] /. sol}, {x, 0, l}]]]
(* 0.064737 *)
```

Can `Plot` be sped up?  Maybe there is a nice way to extract a 1D InterpolatingFunction slice from a 2D InterpolatingFunction?

Comment: If you don't need too much accuracy, `FunctionInterpolation[]` is usable for slicing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@MichaelE2's slice-taking solution works great, but it's a bit cumbersome to use.  Here's an idea based on it, which overloads the definition of `InterpolatingFunction` that makes it transparent to use, and also work on the other dimension.

```
Unprotect[InterpolatingFunction];

InterpolatingFunction[stuff___][var_Symbol, num_?NumericQ] := Module[{if, grid},
  if = InterpolatingFunction[stuff];
  grid = (InterpolatingFunction[stuff])["Grid"];

  Return[(Interpolation@Transpose@{
    grid[[All, 1, {1}]], (* extract x-grid *) 
    if[grid[[All, 1, 1]], num]
     })[var]]
];

InterpolatingFunction[stuff___][num_?NumericQ, var_Symbol] := Module[{if, grid},
  if = InterpolatingFunction[stuff];
  grid = (InterpolatingFunction[stuff])["Grid"];

  Return[(Interpolation@Transpose@{
    grid[[1, All, {2}]], (* extract t-grid *)
    if[num, grid[[1, All, 2]]]
     })[var]]
];

Protect[InterpolatingFunction];
```

In action:

```
l = 100;
tmax = 30;
pts = 1000; (* # grid points *)

sol = NDSolve[{
  D[n[x, t], t] == n[x, t] (1 - n[x, t]) + D[n[x, t], {x, 2}],
  n[x, 0] == If[45 < x < 55, 1, 0], n[0, t] == n[l, t]}, {n}, {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, l}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> pts}}][[1]];

First@Timing[Plot[Evaluate[n[x, 15] /. sol], {x, 0, l}]]
(* 0.3865 *)

Plot[Evaluate[n[x, 15] /. sol], {x, 0, l}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[Evaluate[n[20, t] /. sol], {t, 0, tmax}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is my first attempt at modifying built-in functions, so let me know if it might be improved or if it might break anything!

Comment: I've since been warned that modifying built-in commands is generally bad practice.  This solution worked nicely for me, but use it at your own risk!

Answer (score 4):

Extract the appropriate values and re-interpolate. If we extract the derivative values (optional), you get the normal cubic Hermite interpolation type produced by `NDSolve` on a first-order ODE.  If `t` is a grid point, then the derivatives at the values of `x` on the grid should be stored (as computed from the PDE) in the `InterpolatingFunction`. Between grid points, these will be interpolated.  It makes little difference to the plot, so you can omit and reduce the time a little more.

```
(if = n /. First@sol;
  grid = if["Grid"];
  slice = Interpolation@Transpose@{
      grid[[All, 1, {1}]],                (* extract x-grid *)
      if[grid[[All, 1, 1]], 15.],         (* extract n-values on x-grid at t == 15 *)
      Derivative[1, 0][if][grid[[All, 1, 1]], 15.] (* derivative values *)
     }) // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[slice[x], {x, 0, 100}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks, this is great!  I used this as the basis for my own answer below.

Comment: What if I want a slice parallel to x-t plane, e.g. the locus of points where `n[t,x]==1`?

Answer (score 2):

Another idea is to use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) to extract the slice for you.

```
if = n /. First @ sol;
slice = NDSolveValue[
    {g'[x] == Derivative[1,0][if][x,15], g[0]==if[0,15]}, 
    g,
    {x, 0, 100}
];
```

Visualization:

```
Plot[slice[x], {x, 0, 100}]
```

[image]