# Find x at a given t and f(x,t) == constant from a system of coupled PDE

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, numerics

Is it possible to find the speed of a moving front (produced by the below code) in which modulating beta changes the speed of the front?

Basically, I am trying to map the x-values of f(x,t)=0.5 against the corresponding t values, get the slope (velocity of the front), and then map those at various beta.

```
Manipulate[
 sol2 = NDSolve[{D[sub[rad, tim], 
      tim] == -(sub[rad, tim]) (en[rad, tim]), 
    D[en[rad, 
        tim] + ((sub[rad, tim]*en[rad, tim])/(k2 + k1f/(s0*k1r))), 
      tim] == (1/(k2/(k2 + k1r)))*(D0/((length^2) e0*k1f))*
      D[(Exp[beta (1 - sub[rad, tim])] D[en[rad, tim], rad]), rad],
    (*initial conditions*)
    sub[rad, 0] == s0, en[rad, 0] == 0,(*boundary conditions*)
    en[0, tim] == 1, sub[1, tim] == 1}, {sub, en}, {rad, 0, 1}, {tim, 
    0, 10}];
 Plot[Evaluate[
   Table[{sub[rad, tim], en[rad, tim]} /. sol2, {tim, 3, 10}]], {rad, 
   0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesLabel -> {"Front Position", "Concentration"}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"substrate", "enzyme"}],
 {{s0, 1}, 1, 10, 1},
 {{k2, .5}, 0.1, 1},
 {{k1r, 0.5}, 0.1, 1},
 {{k1f, 1}, 1, 10, 1},
 {{r0, 1}, 0, 1},
 {{e0, 1}, 0.1, 1},
 {{D0, .001}, 0.001, 1},
 {{length, 1}, 1, 10},
 {{beta, 6}, 0, 6}]
```

[image: concentration of enzyme en(r,t) at t=3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

Answer (score 2):

Tracking the front position via the maximum of the derivative and borrowing code from: [Plot 1D slice of 2D InterpolatingFunction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128731/plot-1d-slice-of-2d-interpolatingfunction), you can get what you want:

```
timePositionData = Table[
  (** get 1d interpolating function slice from 2d interpolating function **)
  if = en /. First@sol2;
  grid = if["Grid"];
  slice = 
    Interpolation@Transpose@{grid[[All, 1, {1}]], (** extract x-grid **)
     if[grid[[All, 1, 1]], t],                    (** extract n-values on x-grid at t **)
     Derivative[1, 0][if][grid[[All, 1, 1]], t]   (** derivative values **)};
   (** get global maximum of absolute front derivative for front position **)
   {t, x /. NMaximize[{Abs[slice'[x]], 0 < x < 1}, x][[2]]}
, {t, 3, 10, 0.1}];
```

With

```
Grid[{{
 ListPlot[timePositionData, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"time", "position"}, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 20], ImageSize -> 400]}, {
 Plot[Interpolation[timePositionData]'[t], {t, 3, 10}, 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"time", "velocity"}, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 20], ImageSize -> 400]}}]
```

your data leads to some nice plots:

[image]

If you want even more fine-grained control over your front position, you might be interested in: https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.112.148305