# how we can extract the value of the solution of a PDE in a point x? (NDSolve)

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-value, heat-equation, resolve

Please I need your help, I calculate the solution of heat equation using methode of line
This is my code:

```
n = 10    
grid = 1/n  Range[0, n];
d1 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], grid];
d2 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[2], grid];
M1 = d1["DifferentiationMatrix"];
M2 = d2["DifferentiationMatrix"];
y00[t_] := Sqrt[2] Sin[Pi t];
T= 0.02;
tab = Table[u[i][t], {i, Length[grid]} ];
tab1 = Table[u[i], {i, Length[grid]} ];
ux = M1.tab;
uxx = M2.tab;
solu1   = D[u[1][t], t] == First[ux];
solu2 = D[u[n + 1][t], t] == -Last[ux];
solu3 = Table[D[u[i][t], t] == uxx[[i]], {i, 2, n}];
solu4 = Table[u[i][0] == y00[grid[[i]]], {i, Length[grid]}];
sol1 = NDSolve[{solu1, solu2, solu3, solu4}, tab1, {t, 0, T}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MaxPoints" -> 25}}];
```

Now that I have calculated the solution "sol1". I need to approximate the value of this solution in $t = T$ in the space $ grid$ something like

```
h = Table [sol1 [grid[[i]],T],{i,Length[grid]}]
```

but this is not working for me, can anyone help me with that please??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot 1D slice of 2D InterpolatingFunction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128731/plot-1d-slice-of-2d-interpolatingfunction)

Comment: @ChrisK  I don't think so, in my case the solution is a list, which is different from what the answer you mention presents! I am not sure how this answer could help me!

Comment: You’re not using `sol1` in the way solutions are used in the `NDSolve` documentation. You could reread it. Or perhaps you could change `NDSolve` to `NDSolveValue`, and then `sol[x, t]` would yield numeric values when `x` and `t` are numeric values.

Comment: @ChrisK  Is this the right comment :                                                                          
$ Table[ u[i][\[Tau]] /. sol1[[1]], {i, Length[grid]}] $

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand your question correctly. You calculate the temp. as a function of time on a grid with 11 points. At each point the temp. is a scalar function u[i], i=1..11. The solution sol1 is a list of the u[i].

With these preliminaries we can get the function values for a specific time (e.g. T) by first creating a list of function names:

```
us = Table[u[i], {i, 11}]
```

Then we can replace the names by the actual functions:

```
funs = us /. sol1[[1]]
```

Now we have a list of functions that give the temp. for some time t. To evaluate all these functions for a specific time we may use e.g. `Through`. For the time `T=0.02` we get:

```
Through[funs[T]]

(* {0.0727245, 0.390278, 0.694079, 0.942859, 1.10506, 1.16129, 1.10506, \
0.942859, 0.694079, 0.390278, 0.0727245} *)
```

Comment: I think your answer is exact. Thank you, I used this way: $ Table[ u[i][T] /. sol1[[1]], {i, Length[grid]}]$ it gives  the same results and it's shorter.